# CLion не понимает библиотеку iostream

Tags: c++, clion

CLion не видит библиотеку iostream. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чисто визуально, все компиляется нормально, но  на всё, что связано с iostream, он ругается. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Искал ответы, не нашёл.

Comment: А у вас тип проекта точно `c++`? И установлен ли у вас `MinGW`?

Comment: И если установлен, то записан ли он в PATH?